# MySQL load data infile as a php script for crn

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cron

Okay so I have this sql:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/file.csv' INTO TABLE episodes FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (title, link, date_aired, season, series_id)
```

When I run it in phpmyadmin it works fine. It loads the records from the csv to the table very fast. So as I need this to be done a few times a day I planned to make a cron job out of it. So just to test it I put this sql into a php script so I can execute it using cron. But here is the problem. I ran the script on my own, manually to check if it works. Indeed it works it insert the data into the table, however the script is still running (the page is still loading) and it did what it had to do. So I left it a few more minutes but it is still loading. So to me it seems it went into a kind of endless loop, however there are no loops in the script. This is the significant part of the code from the script:

```
$sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/file.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE episodes FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (title, link, date_aired, season, series_id)";
$query = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

Mind also that I did escape all the characters properly and the query does work, however the page keeps loading. Will this interfere with my other cron jobs. And how can I stop this, except puting a certain timeout value.

Comment: Have you tried a full path to the INFILE? cron might not be able to find the input file.

Comment: I removed the full path when I posted here, just because of the length, replaced it with this dummy path. However it's not the problem here.

Comment: I'd just suggest adding some debugging to your script, in that case - get it to write to a log file, and try to narrow it down. Make sure that the right file is being opened; maybe try with a cut-down version of the CSV with just one line in it?

Comment: No it's not that. What I want to say is that the script does everything fine, insert the data into the db. But after it does so, the page still keeps loading although the script has inserted the data into the db.

Comment: What else does the code do after the insert? It won't interfere with other cron jobs in itself, though if you do have lots of these running, the server is going to start slowing down.

Comment: Just now did I see that the query was in a loop, missed a bracket :(

Comment: No problem. Feel free to add that as an answer and mark the question as Solved when you can.

Answer (score 0):

The script works fine now, the query just got tangled in a previous loop somehow.